# Error in annotating row names as data points in a PCA plot

Tags: bioconductor, ggplot2, pca

I made a PCA plot and was trying to plot the eigenvenctors in R so that each data point is actually the sample name. All the samples are in column 1. The following are the R commands I am using:

```
    fn <- "Plot.txt"
    evecdat <- read.table(fn, col.names=c("Sample", "PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4", "PC5", "PC6", "PC7", "PC8", "PC9", "PC10", "pc11","pc12", "pc13", "pc14", "pc15","pc16", "pc17", "pc18", "pc19", "pc20", "pop", "color"))
    jpeg("Plot1.jpeg", width = 20, height = 20, units = 'in', res = 300)
    identify(evecdat$PC1, evecdat$PC2  = NULL, labels = seq_along(evecdat$Sample), pos = TRUE, n = length(evecdat$Sample), plot = FALSE, atpen = FALSE, offset = 0.5, tolerance = 0.25, …)

    plot(evecdat$PC1, evecdat$PC2, col=as.vector(evecdat$color), xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2", pch="24", cex.lab=2.5, cex=1.5, cex.axis=1)
    legend("topright", ncol=1, legend=c("X", "Y", "Z"), col=c("Blue", "Red", "Green"), pch="24", cex=2, bty = "o")
    while (!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()
```

Here, all the row names are under the Sample column name that I defined earlier.

Comment: We don't have the "Plot.txt" data file so we can't test, but what problem do you have with the code? You get the plot without the name of the samples? Have you looked at  `text`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
plot(evecdat$PC1, evecdat$PC2, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2", pch="24", cex.lab=2.5, cex.axis=1, type="n")  
text(evecdat$PC1, evecdat$PC2, evecdat$Sample, col=as.vector(evecdat$color))
```

This should plot the sample names as text (taken from the `evecdat$Sample` column), colored as specified in the `evecdat$color` column. See `?text` for details.